# How to use 'cutat' insted of 'community.to.membership' in code,

Tags: r, igraph

I’d like to run the example script from the page http://www.babelgraph.org/wp/?p=1,
but without the function **community.to.membership**. I have tried the function **cutat**, but I have error. The code is below:

```
library(igraph) 
ga.data <- read.csv('ga_edgelist.csv', header=TRUE) 
g <- graph.data.frame(ga.data, directed=FALSE) 
gnc <- edge.betweenness.community(g, directed=FALSE) 
gn.groups <- cutat(g, steps=25) #**Error: Not a community structure**
modularity(g, gn.groups)
V(g)$color <- gn.groups 
V(g)$size <- degree(g) * 2 # multiply by 2 for scale 
plot(g)
```

Could somebody please help me to fiх the error?

Comment: @Gabor, thanks you. Could you please show how to change a default number of groups? In above example the number of groups is 7. Is it possible to change this number (for example, on 5) in library igraph for Newman's algorithm?